# Why the cursor is not created again?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

I've got this code that only returns data the first time the loop is executed. The other times, despite there are data in the database and the query is well defined, the cursor doesn't return anything. And I don't know why, because each time the loop is executed, the connection and the cursor are created.

```
def get_team_colour_map(self, players, id_competition):
    tcm = FIBAColourMap()
    for p in players:
        args = [p["id"], id_competition]
        conn = pymysql.Connect(host = DDBB.DDBB_FIBA_HOST,
                                      user = DDBB.DDBB_FIBA_USER,
                                      password = DDBB.DDBB_FIBA_PSWD,
                                      db = DDBB.DDBB_FIBA_NAME,
                                      charset = DDBB.DDBB_FIBA_CHARSET,
                                      cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            print("id player: {}".format(p["id"]))
            print("args: {}".format(args))
            cursor.execute("select sc.* from tbl030_shots_chart sc, tbl006_player_team pt, tbl007_game g, tbl004_jornada j, tbl012_competition c where pt.id = %s and pt.id_player_feb = sc.id_fiba and sc.id_game = g.id and g.id_jornada = j.id and j.id_competition = c.id and c.id = %s", args)
            data = cursor.fetchall()
            print("data: {}".format(data))
            print("Total rows: {}".format(cursor.rowcount))
            if cursor.rowcount > 0:
                for s in data:
                    x = float(FIBASCReport.adjust_x(s["x"]))
                    y = float(FIBASCReport.adjust_y(s["y"]))
                    color = tcm.image.getpixel((x,y))
                    color = ("#%02x%02x%02x" % color).upper()
                    if tcm.exists_color(color):
                        if int(s["m"]) == 0:
                            tcm.set_scored_shots(color, 1)
                        else:
                            tcm.set_failed_shots(color, 1)
                    else:
                        if int(s["m"]) == 0:
                            tcm.set_scored_shots("OTROS", 1)
                        else:
                            tcm.set_failed_shots("OTROS", 1)
            else:
                #tcm = None
                print("Jugadora con id: {} NO ha realizado ningún tiro en competición: {}".format(p["id"], id_competition))
    return tcm
```

In this code, cursor.fetchall() returns data the first query but the next queries return empty results.

Answer (score 2):

Try resetting your cursor after the loop has run, in order to get a 'clean' cursor on each loop:

```
 if cursor.rowcount > 0:
            for s in data:
                x = float(FIBASCReport.adjust_x(s["x"]))
                y = float(FIBASCReport.adjust_y(s["y"]))
                color = tcm.image.getpixel((x,y))
                color = ("#%02x%02x%02x" % color).upper()
                if tcm.exists_color(color):
                    if int(s["m"]) == 0:
                        tcm.set_scored_shots(color, 1)
                    else:
                        tcm.set_failed_shots(color, 1)
                else:
                    if int(s["m"]) == 0:
                        tcm.set_scored_shots("OTROS", 1)
                    else:
                        tcm.set_failed_shots("OTROS", 1)
                cursor.reset()
```

Comment: Hi @Tjofoed!!! It doesn't work to me :( I've got an error: AttributeError: 'DictCursor' object has no attribute 'reset'

Comment: Ah, of course not!
I found this link, which might explain everything a bit more clearly
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796517/navigating-cursor-rows-in-sqlite-can-we-rewind-reset-the-cursor-i-e-go-back-to
Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you @Tjofed but my problem is another. I don't know why the cursor is not created again when I restart the connection in each for loop. I don't want to go back and forward after I make a query. I want to make a query each time I execute the for loop. Each time starts the for loop the connection is created again. And I don't know why it works the first time but the other times doesn't work when I create the connection all of the times the for loop is started.